# Mock Method with Exit

Tags: php, unit-testing, wordpress, mocking

I'm trying to test a method that redirects and exits (exit is necessary).

1.Approach => In my first approach I intend to make return a value from RedirectToHome (I know it nevers returns any stuff as it dies). Is just for the test to work.
2. Is there a better way to test this method?

```
class MyClass {
  public function ExecuteProcess() {
    if (condition1) { 
    // Do some stuff
    } else {
       // 1. Approach
       return $this->RedirectToHome();
       // 2. Approach ?
    }
  }

  public function RedirectToHome() {
    wp_redirect();
    exit();
  }
 }
```

And the Test Code:

```
public function test_MyClass() {

    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('MyClass')
->setMethods(array('RedirectToHome'))
->getMock();

$mock->expects($this->once())
    ->method('RedirectToHome')
    ->will($this->returnValue(true))

  $mock->ExecuteProcess();
  // Asert
```